# MySQL Copy one column to another column in the same table for billions of rows takes too long

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In MySQL (MariaDB actually) I have the following table:

```
table1:  
   id  |  val1  |  val2  |  val3  |  val4  |  val5
----------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to copy val3 to val1 with the following statement:

```
UPDATE table1 SET val1=val3 where id=some_id;
```

The UPDATE command works but takes WAY too long, it takes 813 seconds for 15 Million rows.  I have ~200 Billion rows to update, so it will take FOREVER...I think about 118 days.

Any tricks / suggestions on how to do this faster?

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table1;  

CREATE TABLE `table1` (  
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `val1` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `val2` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `val3` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `val4` binary(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\0',  
  `val5` float DEFAULT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`val1`,`val2`,`val3`)  
) ENGINE=TokuDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 `COMPRESSION`=TOKUDB_LZMA
```

Comment: Do you have a index on id?  Can you add the execution plan to your question?

Comment: Why is this updating more than 1 row? Isn't `id` a unique ID column?

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. Are there 15 million rows with the same value in the `id` column? Or, are you running 15 million individual `UPDATE` statements?

Comment: This kind of problem is sometimes indicative of poor design, but I guess if you've got 200 billion rows, you probably know that already

Comment: Yes, I ran a 'SHOW INDEX FROM mydb.table1' and id, val1, val2, and val3 have Key_name=PRIMARY and Index_Type=BTREE

Comment: @Strawberry... I so want to put my pinky finger to the corner of my mouth and say (Dr.Evil style)...  "one meeel-yun rows"

Comment: Can you show the schema for the table? `show create table table1`?

Comment: @spencer, yes it is ambiguous I am sorry.  Yes, the id column has 15 million rows with the same id.  Maybe I should give it a different name in this question.  When I ran it I limited it with the 'where id = some_id'

Comment: @spencer should I change the name of 'id' in my post to just 'val0', so it is a little less confusing?  After all, it's not really a unique id.

Comment: @Barmar, I added this to the original post.  Maybe I should change the name of the column of 'id' to 'val0' in my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: One reason this is so slow is that updating `val1` requires re-indexing the row. So every update has to change both the table data and the index.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you.  Stupid question...can I remove the index, make the update and then add back the index?  I am not a MySQL expert as you can probably already tell.

Answer (score 0):

Update this column would make the entire row to be rewritten. It would demand time and it would be IO expensive. Two options:

1. Use a ternary condition while selecting data: Select IF(some_id =id, val3, val1)...
2. Split your query among different updates: update table set val1=val3 where id=some_id and val1<>val3 and id>=x and id<= x+1000000. If you can run the same query using different x's (1,1000001,2000001,...) it would make better use of your server cores, instead of using a single one. And once one of those queries end you would know that this part of the job is done. Your bottleneck will be IO and the number of cores you will be able to use.

   2.1. Important point: in order to rewrite the least as possible, please make sure that you only update if val1<>val3

Comment: `val1 <> val3` means the same thing as `val3 <> val1` (at least to the computer).

Comment: See [my blog on chunking](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks), but probably do it only on `id` since val1 is being stepped on.  You might need to all rows with a given `id` as one chunk, then move to the next id.

Comment: @Rick, originally otaviofcs had val3 <> val5, which he has since changed since my question.  I was just making sure I understood correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: @harley is right, I switch the columns since I answer

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the primary key, and replacing it with a non-unique index on the `id` field (this is needed to make the `WHERE` clause efficient). Do all the updates. Then remove the `id` index and add back the primary key.

```
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD KEY (id);
do all the updates
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP KEY(id), ADD PRIMARY KEY(id, value1, value2, value3);
```

Comment: let's see if I understand the steps:  `ALTER TABLE table1 DROP PRIMARY KEY;`  `ALTER TABLE table1 ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);`  Then do the updates, then put back the primary key the way it was.  Right?

Comment: The second statement should just be `ADD KEY(id)`. It's not a primary key because it's not unique.

Comment: Thanks.  Is the time it takes to drop the primary key with the `ALTER TABLE` statement dependent on the number of rows in the table?  I tried on a test db and it took 55 seconds with 7 Million rows, so with my production db it will take something like 17 days, if that is the case...unless my calculation is wrong.

Comment: I think dropping the key should be fast, but adding the new key will take time proportional to the table size. But if you don't do this, every `UPDATE` statement will take time proportional to the table size.

Comment: There's no free lunch. Doing a bulk change to a huge table like this is going to be **very** slow.